# How to make the turtle do a certain task after a specific patch is reached?

Tags: simulation, netlogo

Here in my code, I want the turtle( car) while moving when it reaches the patch with green color, to change the variable uncharged_solar_battery and take an U-turn.

```
ask cars
  [ if [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 = green
    [set  uncharged_solar_battery uncharged_solar_battery + 10]
     [lt 180]]
```

After the car reaches the certain patch, no change in value of uncharged_solar_battery occurs.

Comment: Perhaps `[pcolor] of patch-ahead 1` isn't `green` exactly, but just some shade of green? You might try adding debugging output such as `show [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1` to make your turtles talk about they're doing as they do it, to help you understand why they're not behaving as you expected.

Comment: Also, this can't be your actual code, because it isn't valid NetLogo code — the square brackets aren't correct.